# Golang plugin on Intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea, go

I want to use Intellij 13.1.6 as my go app IDE, but there are some problem I can't sovle yet.

The default version of go support plugin installed on Intellij is 0.9.15, but in this version, there are some bugs so that I can build project successfully.

So I try to build the go-plugin jar by myself follow this article:

https://content.pivotal.io/blog/setting-up-the-google-go-plugin-with-intellij-idea-13-on-os-x-10-8-5

But when I click `Prepare Plugin Module 'google-go-language' For Deployment`, it shows errors cause some method can't be found. As the following figure
[image]

I think the problem is the version of my Intellij lack of some lib so that I can't build go-plugin jar successfully. How do I fix this?

Appreciate any replies.

- Intellij Version: 13.1.6
- JDK Version: 1.7
- Go-plugin on GitHub: the latest commit on master branch (0261ffa)

Comment: If you can use Eclipse, GoClipse seem more stable.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It looks like some lib in Intellij 13 didn't support the latest commit in golang plugin. I checkout the commit on previous version then it works. I'll try GoClipse later.

Comment: I recommend either the Sublime Go plugin, or LiteIDE which is a dedicated Go IDE that while a bit ugly, works great and is far more feature rich than any other Go env out ther.e

Answer (score 3):

The latest version of the Go plugin code [requires IntelliJ IDEA 14](https://github.com/mtoader/go-lang-idea-plugin#how-to-use-it).